# Estou atualizando a versão do cordova-android e ela continua a mesma

Tags: apache-cordova

Estou tentando instalar um plugin no cordova, mas ele está reclamando que minha versão não é compatível.

```
Fetching plugin "phonegap-plugin-push" via npm
Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 4.1.1, failed version requirement: >=6.4.0
Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-push' for android
```

E mesmo após atualizar com o comando

```
cordova platform update android
```

Ela segue na mesma versão, alguém sabe como faço para atualizar?

Vou colocar aqui a minha versão atual do cordova e do cordova-android

```
C:\cordova\push>cordova -v
5.3.1

C:\cordova\push>cordova platforms
Installed platforms: android 4.1.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, webos, windows, windows8, wp8

C:\cordova\push>cordova platform update android
Updating android project...
Android project updated with cordova-android@4.1.1

C:\cordova\push>cordova platforms
Installed platforms: android 4.1.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, webos, windows, windows8, wp8
```

Como faço para atualizar?

Comment: Fiz isso, C:\cordova\push>cordova platform remove android
C:\cordova\push>cordova platform add android@6.X.X
e mesmo assim fiquei na versão android 6.1.2, o plugin que estou tentando utilizar requer a versão >=6.4.0

Comment: C:\cordova\push>cordova platform add android@6.4.0
Failed to fetch platform android@6.4.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: version not found: cordova-android@6.4.0

Comment: Desinstale o cordova e instale com a CLI antiga e Depois adicione o android:
>npm install -g cordova@5.4.1 && cordova platform add android@4.1.1